# Unity 5.1.1f1 Facebook SDK 6.2.2 Error 400: Bad request on getting player picture on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I got stuck at getting profile picture on iOS devices. **It works well on Editor, Android devices, even Facebook graph**. After FB.init() called successfully, i call

```
string url = Util.GetPictureURL(fID, 128, 128);
FB.API(url, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, AvatarAPICallback);
```

Following is the url after debugged:

v2.5/626213070847481/picture?g&width=128&height=128&redirect=false

on iPhone, it returns error 400: bad request.

Any answer is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the UserID and use WWW to request a user picture.

Example to download a sprite:

```
private IEnumerator DownloadPicture(string userID){
    WWW www= new WWW("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?width=200&height=200");
    yield return www;

    if(www.error==null)
        userPicture = Sprite.Create ((www.texture as Texture2D), new Rect (new Vector2 (0, 0), new Vector2 (www.texture.width, www.texture.height)), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f));
    else
        userPicture = defaultPicture;
}
```

Comment: it resolved my problem but the main reason is Unity Facebook SDK has bug. It's confirmed in there: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1055166274505844/